# The options showing after choosing needs improvement in the triage queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

Recently there was a change in the triage queue options. So I read [the detailed guide for triaging questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/2359227).

If one hit flag, and chooses needs improvement, those are the options he gets:

- Duplicate
- A community specific reason
- Needs details or clarity
- Needs more focus
- Opinion-Based

I was wondering, why are those the options being seen. According to the guidelines, for example if a post is missing details, the action should be taken is Needs author edit. Is there any reason to flag the question Needs details or clarity from the Flag option?

If not, why is it showing there? Same of course applies for Needs more focus and Opinion-Based.

The Duplicate option is shown in the first screen(before hitting needs improvement), so I am not sure why there is a duplicate of this option.

On the other way around, when choosing Needs author edit, I can choose A community specific reason, and there I can choose, for example Blatantly off-topic, if the question for example was not written in english. Why are the community specific reasons are shown on the Needs author edit? Is there any reason I'd choose this combination?

Comment: Personally, i think the choice is more based on UX. Even if they end up in the same(ish) place, the reasons for the 2 are different. If a post is rude, or completely off topic (asks about Licensing for example) that would be a flag option. User edit would be more because it's in the wrong language, perhaps need an [mre] added, or the error they say they get. They lead to the same place, but you won't get people selecting "requires editting" for the reason "needs the error to be added by the OP in an edit"; which means far less triage queue bans.

Comment: Have you also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402478/announcing-tweaks-to-the-triage-queue ?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: If the post is spam you're going to flag rather than choose needs author edit aren't you?

Comment: The best I can make out is, the 'flag' button gives the menu you get by clicking on the 'needs improvement' choice of the 'flag' word button on a post on a q&a page, although the destination menu characterizes itself as a 'needs closing' menu. That menu & the menus from the 'flag' word button have a long history. I don't see much  underlying "conceptual integrity" for the flag-queue system though.

Answer (score 7):

Since they're relevant, I'll put two comments from the recent [Announcing tweaks to the Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402478/11047824) post here:

> Do we really need both options, "Flag." and "Needs author edit"? One option should be enough [. . .] <sup>[Link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402478/announcing-tweaks-to-the-triage-queue#comment805244_402478)</sup>
> *– [@Tom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom)*

> Our philosophy here was to err on the side of surfacing more options to make it more obvious that "Needs author edit" is a possible choice, instead of giving people more room to make mistakes. Even though you can technically accomplish all you'd like from the Flag option, we want to make sure that questions that need author edit are properly routed. <sup>[Link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402478/announcing-tweaks-to-the-triage-queue#comment805247_402478)</sup>
> *– [@kristinalustig ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1530044/kristinalustig) (OP of announcement)*

The idea is that <kbd>Flag</kbd> can be used for exactly what it says on the tin- flagging a question, in any shape or form that may take.

The new <kbd>Needs Author Edit</kbd> option opens directly to the needs improvement flag dialogue, simply to add clarity for reviewers. If a question needs an edit from the OP, that is, needs added information or other clarification that *only* the OP can reasonably provide, then closing the question is what needs to happen. The new button just reduces the overall friction to get there.

You've correctly noted that you can do both from just the flag option, but adding this extra button helps clarify what has presented itself as [a significant and consistent hurdle for Triage reviewers in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/295650). They're designed to use the existing flagging dialogue structure, and don't create their own system for something that already exists.

As for the design of the flag pop-up itself, I dug and dug and dug and honestly couldn't find a single source on *why* the flag dialogue is designed exactly the way it is.
I found reference to the fact that [flags are split into 4 types](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270617/11047824), which clearly influences the structure, and there's also clearly an effort to communicate which flag options lead to closures (eg. to a new user, the dupe flag may not sound like a closing-flag at first). But beyond this, it seems it's a little bit of a mystery.

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood my question. The new Needs author button is great. What I don't understand is why from this button I can get to blatantly off topic. Or why can I get from flag to Need details or clarity.

Comment: I think I ran on a bit of a tangent, but I feel it's still relevant, especially the final paragraph. Since there was no alteration done to the flag dialogue, and since the review buttons are just shortcuts to different places of that dialogue, you'll inevitably be able to reach "blatantly off-topic" from author edit.

Comment: This answer answered my question, so thank you

Answer (score 2):

Needs author edit is merely a shortcut. It's there to save you a mouse click in the common case that you want to close a post for one of the "Needs improvement" reasons.

So the duplication via the Flags option seems to be [by design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402478/announcing-tweaks-to-the-triage-queue).

> "Needs author edit” is added as an option.
>
> This option functions fairly similarly to the “Flag” option, except that it opens directly to the close dialog instead of the flag dialog.

The simple existence of a button labelled "Needs author edit” also acts as a hint for those new to the triage queue as to what to do when a post can only be fixed by original author editing i.e. it's missing crucial information that only the OP can supply. Many used to choose the superficially tempting but ultimately incorrect option of "Requires Editing". We ought to get far fewer cases of incorrect triage activity now and far fewer people review banned because of it.