# Clarifying the flag tree in the triage queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

The purpose of this question, is to try to ease up the triage queue, and help reviewers make less mistakes while reviewing.

After asking [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402515/2359227) question, I understood that I have to draw my question to make it clearer.

The triage queue options tree is:

[image]

I deliberately copied the "duplicated vertices" because even if today they are written once, in the same view, it doesn't have to be this way, I assume.

I wanted to ask about 4 edges of this tree, and I have given them numbers so I can use it as their names:

- "edge 1" will be the edge from "Flag" to "Needs improvement"
- "edge 2" will be the edge from "Needs improvement" to "A community specific reason"
- "edge 3" will be the edge from "Needs author edit" to "A community specific reason"
- "edge 4" will be the edge from "Needs author edit" to "Duplicate"

Let's start from "edge 1". Let's assume one decided to flag the question, 5 options are opened, and "Needs improvement" was chosen. Now he gets a new window, where 3 out of 5 options are invalid for this scenario: Needs details or clarity, needs more focus, and Opinion-based. If one of those was appropriate, the reviewer should have chosen earlier the "Needs author edit", instead of flag. another option in this view that is just redundant is Duplicate, which existed in the previous options page. Then, only if choosing "A community specific reason", relevant options are shown. The question is, why not concatenating "edge 1" and "edge 2", and get rid of the vertices we don't need?

Let's move to edges 3 and 4. They are pretty much alike. Let's assume the reviewer thought that the author can improve the question, can it be that the reviewer will now choose a duplicate? or any of the community specific reason? I don't think that this is the purpose. Therefore the question for edges 3 and 4, is why not deleting them, to avoid confusions?

Comment: This is simply because the dialog by pressing flag is the flagging dialog and the dialog by pressing needs author edit is the closure dialog. When you hit 3k reputation they'll be noticeably different (because one uses flags, the other uses close votes), for now, they'll both use flags for you. The only difference for you is the number of clicks, as both the flag dialog and author edit dialog do actually flag. If you ever get up to 3k rep, you'll probably want to prioritise the author edit option (which uses close votes), it's generally more helpful.